# Getting 'dict_keys' object does not support indexing despite casting to list

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, jupyter-notebook

I am using Python 3 and despite of casting to list, I cannot seem to run my program.

This is the function calling:

```
path = euleriancycle(edges)
```

And this is where I have used the keys method:

```
def euleriancycle(e):
    currentnode = list[e.keys()[0]]
    path = [currentnode]
```

I tried to run it without type-casting to list and got this error. After rummaging about this site and similar queries, I followed the solutions suggested and type-cast to list but to no avail. I got the same error.

This is the error track:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-56-356b905111a9> in <module>()
     45             edges[int(edge[0])] = [int(edge[1])]
     46 
---> 47 path = euleriancycle(edges)
     48 print(path)

<ipython-input-56-356b905111a9> in euleriancycle(e)
      1 def euleriancycle(e):
----> 2     currentnode = list[e.keys()[0]]
      3     path = [currentnode]
      4 
      5     while true:

TypeError: 'dict_keys' object does not support indexing
```

Comment: `list(e.keys())[0]` works, but `next(iter(e))` is probably better

Comment: You did *not* cast `e.keys()` to a list before indexing. You tried to cast the *result* of `e.keys()[0]` to a list (albeit with botched indexing syntax, it's `list(...)`, not `list[...]`); you probably meant to use `list(e.keys())[0]` (note the parentheses!) but that's just a verbose way of spelling `list(e)[0]`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `dict_keys` objects, like sets, can not be indexed.

Instead of this:

```
list[e.keys()[0]]
```

The next closest thing would be this:

```
list(e)[0]
```

Python makes no guarantee on what key from the dict will be returned, so you might want to put an ordering on it yourself.

Comment: If the ordering of the keys is significant, use a `collections.OrderedDict`.

Answer (score 3):

You are trying to index the `dict_keys` object, *then* convert that element to a list (syntax error of `list[...]` vs `list(...)` aside). You need to convert the entire object to a list first, *then* index it.

```
currentnode = list[e.keys()[0]]   # Wrong
currentnode = list(e.keys()[0])   # Less wrong, but still wrong
currentnode = list(e.keys())[0]   # Right
```

`list` takes any iterable, and the iterator returned by a dictionary is just an iterator over its keys, so you don't need to call `keys` explicitly.

```
currentnode = list(e)[0]
```